# Thread FetcherThread has no more work available. fetch of .com/ failed with: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: nutch

While giving **bin/nutch fetch $s1** while following https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial facing the below issue

```
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1
fetch of http://nutch.apache.org/ failed with: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

please sort out what is this happening?

Comment: i am trying to crawl data from website using nutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**remove your crawl folder first.**

**run the below commands:**

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb dmoz
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments
s1=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
echo $s1
bin/nutch fetch $s1
bin/nutch parse $s1
bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1
```

initiate all the configuration like url under dmoz, nutch-site.xml, etc